# $.ajax post sends no body?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ajax

I'm doing a simple post request, but my server says the post request has no body. Every key has an "undefined" value. Here is my post request:

```js
let alert_title = 'Alert';
let alert_body = 'Alert';
let show_alert = 4;

console.log(handlePost(show_alert));

function handlePost(showAlert) {
  var params = new Object();
  params.alert_id = 1;
  params.alert_title = alert_title;
  params.alert_body = alert_body;
  params.show_alert = Number(show_alert);
  params.database_host = "my.ip.address";
  params.database_name = "my-database-name";
  console.log(params);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mydomain/api/UpdateAlert",
    data: params, 
    ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first of all, there is an easy way to write objects: `let params = { paramName: paramValue }`. secondly, try removing the contentType and dataType properties from the $.ajax function

Comment: You send the data as FormData. Maybe your server expect it as JSON-serialized payload.

Comment: I made both changes and the changes, but the values are still showing undefined on the server. I'm trying to get the values this way:

const { database_host, database_name, alert_id, alert_title, alert_body, show_alert } = req.body;

Comment: How is this related to PHP??

Answer (score 0):

You are posting an object directly. Try to convert to JSON string before posting with `JSON.stringify(params);`